# Como remover DIV especifica com javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Ola eu possuo uma tela de cadastro de informações académicas; preciso que esse campo possa ser duplicado e removido, mas quando removo apenas a primeira DIV e excluída; utilizo o javascrip abaixo, quando a pessoa clona o campo aparece o 'X' para excluir, mas se ela duplicar mais de uma vez o ultimo 'X' irá excluir o primeiro campo, não importa o 'X' sempre removera o primeiro campo.

HTML:

```
<div id="academico" class="tab-pane fade">
                            <div id="academico1">
                                <div class="col-xs-9">
                                    <label for="ex3">Formação</label>
                                    <input class="form-control input-sm" title="Digite o nome do curso" id="FormacaoAcademica" name="estudo[]" type="text" >
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <label for="ex3">Status</label>
                                    <select class="form-control input-sm" id="FormacaoAcademica" name="estudo[]" >
                                        <option selected disabled>Selecione</option>
                                        <option>Cursando</option>
                                        <option>Concluido</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9">
                                    <label for="ex3">Nível</label>
                                    <input class="form-control input-sm" title="Especifique se o curso trata-se de curso tecnico, graduação ou pos-graduação"  name="estudo[]" type="text" id="FormacaoAcademica">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <label for="ex3">Ano de conclusão</label>
                                    <input class="form-control input-sm" title="Digite o Ano de Conclusão"  name="estudo[]" type="text" id="FormacaoAcademica">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3" id="botoesacademico">
                                    <a class="hidden" href="javascript:void(0)" id="btnova_tarefa" onclick="Removeacademico()" title="Remover"><img src="imagens/rem.png"/></a>
                                </div>
                                <hr style="clear:both;">
                            </div>
                            <center><a class="inline"  href="javascript:void(0)" id="btnova_tarefa" onclick="Clonaacademico()" title="Adicionar"><img src="imagens/add.png"/></a></center>
                        </div>
```

javascrip para Clonar:

```
function Clonaacademico() { $("#academico1").clone().fadeIn(700).insertBefore($("#academico1")).find('#FormacaoAcademica').val('');
    document.getElementById("btnova_tarefa").setAttribute("class", "inline");
    count = count + 1;}
```

Javascrip para excluir:

```
function Removeacademico() {
    $('#academico div#academico1:this').fadeOut(700, function () {
        $('#academico div#academico1:this').remove();
    });}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está clonando um elemento com `id`s que irão se repetir, e com isso a sua função sempre achará o primeiro elemento com a `id` procurada.

> Tenha em mente que um `id` deve ser único na página. Ao clonar
>   elementos, utilize `class` em vez de `id`.

Veja que há vários elementos com `id`s, inclusive você colocou o mesmo `id="FormacaoAcademica"` em todos os elementos de formulário (`select` e `input`), o que deixa seu código incorreto e mais complicado.

Reformulei todo o código (HTML e JavaScript) removendo as incorreções, e utilizei apenas um evento "click" para pegar os cliques nos botões "Adicionar" e "Remover", diferenciando um do outro pelo atributo `title`, ou seja, se o botão clicado tiver no `title` "Adicionar", o elemento é clonado; se tiver "Remover", o respectivo bloco será removido.

Dispensei o uso das funções `Clonaacademico()` e `Removeacademico()` porque o evento `.on("click"...` já controla as funções dos botões, conforme explicado no parágrafo anterior.

Retirei também dos botões o `javascript:void(0)` e usei `preventDefault()`. Este método cancela ação dos links.

Outras explicações você pode ver no código:

```js
// cria o evento "click" para capturar o clique nos botões
$(document).on("click", ".btnova_tarefa", function(e){
   
   e.preventDefault();
   
   var t = $(this).attr("title"); // seleciona o title do elemento
   
   if(t == "Adicionar"){
   
      var p = $(".academico:eq(0)"); // seleciona a primeira div
      var c = p.clone(); // clona a primeira div
   
      c
      .hide() // esconde inicialmente o clone para aplicar o fadeIn
      .insertBefore(p)
      .fadeIn(700)
      .find('select, input') // seleciona elementos select e input
      .val(''); // esvazia os elementos
   
      c
      .find('.hidden')
      .attr("class", "inline btnova_tarefa");

   }else if(t == "Remover"){

      var p = $(this)
      .closest(".academico"); // seleciona o elemento pai com a classe
      
      p
      .fadeOut(350, function(){
         p.remove();
      });

   }
});
```

```css
.hidden{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="academico">
     <div class="col-xs-9">
         <label for="ex3"><strong>Formação</strong></label>
         <input class="form-control input-sm" title="Digite o nome do curso" name="estudo[]" type="text" >
     </div>

     <div class="col-xs-3">
         <label for="ex3">Status</label>
         <select class="form-control input-sm" name="estudo[]" >
             <option selected disabled>Selecione</option>
             <option>Cursando</option>
             <option>Concluido</option>
         </select>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-9">
         <label for="ex3">Nível</label>
         <input class="form-control input-sm" title="Especifique se o curso trata-se de curso tecnico, graduação ou pos-graduação"  name="estudo[]" type="text">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-3">
         <label for="ex3">Ano de conclusão</label>
         <input class="form-control input-sm" title="Digite o Ano de Conclusão"  name="estudo[]" type="text">
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-3 botoesacademico">
         <a class="hidden" href="#" title="Remover"><img src="imagens/rem.png"/></a>
     </div>
     <hr style="clear:both;">
 </div>
 <center><a class="inline btnova_tarefa"  href="#" title="Adicionar"><img src="imagens/add.png"/></a></center>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado sam, ajudou muito mesmo estava quebrando a cabeça com isso, obrigado também pelas dicas, sou muito noob ainda em javascrip e estou envolvido em alguns projetos que esta difícil estudar.

Comment: Olá, o que desenvolveu ajudou bastante, mas tive alguns problemas com o Jquery, como você utilizou a versão 2.1.1, eu mudei no meu programa, mas outras funções passaram a não funcionar, teria alguma dica, utilizei a versão 1.3.2

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, mas consegui resolver aqui; acredito que não seja a melhor forma, mas por enquanto resolve. 

$("#btdel_tarefa").live('click', function() {
   var div = $(this).closest('#academico1');
   div.fadeOut(700, function() {
   div.remove();
 });
});

Answer (score 0):

Você pode identificar individualmente qual o elemento pai com o id academico1 e que remover com o seguinte código.

```
$("#btn-remover").click((e) => {                //evento click do mouse
    e.preventDefault();                         //desativa a função de refresh do link
    $(e.target).parent("#academico1").remove(); //seleciona e remove apenas a div que teve o botão remover clicado.
});
```

Você pode dar uma olhada na documentação do jquery(https://api.jquery.com/) para melhorar um pouco a estrutura do seu código.