# Como excluir elementos HTML usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando fazer um bingo em HTML/JavaScript e no momento preciso excluir uma tabela (cartela) cadastrada assim que o usuário clicar em no botão apagar, como sou iniciante em JavaScript eu fui em vários sites e testei vários comandos mas nenhum funcionou, quem souber me ajude. Aqui vai o código:

```
<!DOCUMENT html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
                #container {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
                  }
                table {
                    border: 1px solid black; 
                    margin: 10px;
                    vertical-align: bottom;
                }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <input type="text" id="nome">
        <input type="button" name="Criar" value="Cadastrar" id="botao">
        <div id="container"></div>


        <script> 
                var nome = window.document.getElementById('nome')
                var botao = window.document.getElementById('botao')
                botao.addEventListener('click',clicar_botao)



                function clicar_botao(){
                    var elemento_bisavo = document.getElementById('container');
                    var elemento_avo = document.createElement('table');
                    var elemento_pai = document.createElement('tr');
                    var elemento_filho = document.createElement('th');
                    var elemento_filho2 = document.createElement('th');
                    var botao_apaga = document.createElement('input');
                    var texto = document.createTextNode(nome.value);

                    elemento_avo.setAttribute("id","avo");
                    botao_apaga.setAttribute("type","button");
                    botao_apaga.setAttribute("value","Apagar");
                    botao_apaga.setAttribute("id","apagar");
                    botao_apaga.setAttribute("onclick","click");


                    function click(){
                        document.getELementById('avo').style.display="none";
                        document.getElementById('avo').style.display="hidden";

                    }
                    elemento_filho.appendChild(texto);
                    elemento_filho2.appendChild(botao_apaga);
                    elemento_bisavo.appendChild(elemento_avo);
                    elemento_avo.appendChild(elemento_pai);
                    elemento_pai.appendChild(elemento_filho);
                    elemento_pai.appendChild(elemento_filho2);
                }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

OBS: o código para excluir a tabela deve ficar dentro da função click, o máximo que eu achei foi uma propriedade para deixar a tabela invisível, mas mesmo assim não funciona.

Comment: / Já tentou? `function click(){
                    document.getELementById('avo').remove();
                    document.getElementById('avo').remove();
                }`

Comment: N achei essa, vou testar agr

Comment: Se dar certo,dar reputação pra mim ,já publiquei minha resposta. Eu espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro que você está criando elementos com id's iguais, o que já é errado. Um id deve ser único na página.

Outro problema é que você está usando `click()` como uma função, o que não pode porque o `click()` já é uma função nativa do JavaScript. Você teria que usar um outro nome, como `clic`, por exemplo.

Como você diz ser iniciante na linguagem, procure aprender nomear objetos (funções, variáveis etc.) sem usar nomes reservados ou nomes de funções nativas.

Outra coisa também é que você colocou a função dentro de outra função. Isso fará com que o atributo onclick que está usando não tenha acesso à função por causa do escopo.

Minha sugestão é criar id's diferentes com uma variável e ir incrementando essa variável e concatenando nos ids, assim gerando ids diferentes, passando para a função como parâmetro que irá remover os elementos criados.

Veja:

```js
var ids = 1;
var nome = window.document.getElementById('nome')
var botao = window.document.getElementById('botao')
botao.addEventListener('click',clicar_botao)

function clic(id){
   document.getElementById('avo'+id).outerHTML = '';
}

function clicar_botao(){
    var elemento_bisavo = document.getElementById('container');
    var elemento_avo = document.createElement('table');
    var elemento_pai = document.createElement('tr');
    var elemento_filho = document.createElement('th');
    var elemento_filho2 = document.createElement('th');
    var botao_apaga = document.createElement('input');
    var texto = document.createTextNode(nome.value);

    elemento_avo.setAttribute("id","avo"+ids);
    botao_apaga.setAttribute("type","button");
    botao_apaga.setAttribute("value","Apagar");
    botao_apaga.setAttribute("onclick","clic("+ids+")");


    elemento_filho.appendChild(texto);
    elemento_filho2.appendChild(botao_apaga);
    elemento_bisavo.appendChild(elemento_avo);
    elemento_avo.appendChild(elemento_pai);
    elemento_pai.appendChild(elemento_filho);
    elemento_pai.appendChild(elemento_filho2);
    ids++;
}
```

```css
#container {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
   }
 table {
     border: 1px solid black; 
     margin: 10px;
     vertical-align: bottom;
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="nome">
<input type="button" name="Criar" value="Cadastrar" id="botao">
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Mas só tem um elemento com o id = "avô", por isso n entendi isso de ficar incrementando ids. Em relação a criação da função eu achava que se criasse ela do lado de fora ia dar erro, já que o elemento_avo n tinha sido criado; sobre o click eu achava que ele só seria ativado quando estivesse dentro do atributo onclick. Obrigado pelas explicações e dicas, vou usar daqui pra frente, só n entendi msm a questão dos ids

Comment: Cada vez que criar o elemento aumentar ids. Ex.: avo1,avo2,avo3...

Comment: @DanielLucas A questão dos id's é o seguinte: veja que vc cria elementos na página com o mesmo id "avo" e "apagar". Não pode haver mais de um elemento na página com o mesmo id, seria a mesma coisa se meu CPF fosse igual ao seu. Em relação a incrementar, eu criei uma variável que começa do 1 e cada vez que um elemento é criado a variável soma +1, ou seja, começa do 1, depois vira 2, 3, 4 etc... com isso eu crio id's diferentes: avo1, avo2, avo3 etc...

Comment: @DanielLucas Veja também que nem colocar id no botão "apagar" foi necessário, porque não ia servir pra nada.

Comment: Caso queria remover todos use método `for (i=1;i<ids;i++) {document.getElementById("avo"+i).remove(); }`

Comment: ah, entendi agr, vlw de nono pela paciência e pela explicação

Comment: @DanielLucas de nada, jovem. Já sabe o que fazer quando uma resposta pras suas perguntas for satisfatória?

Comment: Eu ia usar o id "apagar" pra poder pegar o botão com o getElement, mas nem foi necessário msm  usando essa forma que vc mostrou

Comment: @DanielLucas Quando vc estiver mais familiarizado com a linguagem, vai perceber que vai usar mt pouca vezes ids. Geralmente o uso excessivo de ids é de quem não conhece mt a linguagem e acha nos ids uma forma fácil de chegar num objetivo, mas na maioria das vezes faz é complicar mais rs.. Abs!

Comment: @Sam aperta no botão de ^ pra marcar como útil? Sou novo aqui tbm kkk

Comment: Já votei no ^....

Comment: Eu tô falando da sua resposta

Comment: @MauryDeveloper boa ideia, vou fazer um botão pra apagar tudo, vlw

Comment: @DanielLucas A tah, entendi.... vc pode votar sim se quiser dar uns pontos extras pra que respondeu algo que vc achou útil.

Comment: @Sam é pq vc tinha perguntado se eu sabia o que fazer quando uma reposta fosse satisfatória, é só apertar no ^ da pessoa que respondeu ou faz mais coisa?

Comment: Vc deve marcar apenas 1 resposta com ✔ (a que vc achou melhor) e pode votar ^ nas respostas que quiser, mesmo na que vc marcou ✔.

Comment: @Daniel Lucas Qualquer coisa pergunte. Eu estou 100% online. Grande abraço e boa sorte na carreira de desenvolvedor. Sam já dei voto a favor a ti.

Comment: Eu faço curso técnico no IFRN, mas planejo seguir na área. Obrigado pela força, abração

Answer (score -1):

Olá,use método `remove()`.
Tenha ids diferentes.
Mude nome da função pra `_click`

```js
function _click(){
   document.getELementById('avo1').remove();
   document.getElementById('avo2').remove(); 
}
```

Alguns links importantes:
[Remover elemento da página com javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4605/remover-elemento-da-p%C3%A1gina-com-javascript)

[Como remover DIV especifica com javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316367/como-remover-div-especifica-com-javascript)

http://everon.com.br/2017/04/22/javascript-remover-um-elemento-html-de-uma-pagina/

Eu espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Vish, pelo remove n deu certo aki, mas obrigado por responder :)

Comment: Isso foi exemplo. Só fiz dar uma luz pra outros terem resposta melhores.